# How to resize a background image to match the canvas? FabricJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, fabricjs

So I am currently having a problem. I am using Meteor.js and Fabric.js, and I am trying to figure out how to rescale an image to fit into the canvas. Currently this is my code:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
 canvas.setWidth(800);
 canvas.setHeight(800);
 var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
 var canvasWidth = canvas.width;

 //Just a debug statement console.log(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

 var bgImg = new fabric.Image();
 bgImg.setSrc('http://www.aamcocolorado.com/images/Highway-
 Traffic.jpg');
 bgImg.set({
    top: canvasHeight / 2,
    left: canvasWidth / 2,
    scaleX: canvasWidth/bgImg.width,
    scaleY: canvasHeight/bgImg.height,
 });

 canvas.setBackgroundImage(bgImg);
```

The result of this is that I am getting a snippet of the image, that is not scaled to the correct size. Wondering what I was missing?

(Have already checked out other answers, but was not able how to apply it to Meteor, am a JS beginner)

Comment: I'd imagine that `bgImg.setSrc` is asynchronous, so perhaps you need to wait for the image to load so that it's widht and height are known - see [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setSrc) - optional call back (second argument) is called when the image has completed loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setSrc is asynchronous. You can provide a function as a callback to run after the image loads:

var

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
canvas.setWidth(800);
canvas.setHeight(800);
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;

//Just a debug statement console.log(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

var bgImg = new fabric.Image();
bgImg.setSrc('http://www.aamcocolorado.com/images/Highway-Traffic.jpg', function () {
  bgImg.set({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    scaleX: canvasWidth/bgImg.width,
    scaleY: canvasHeight/bgImg.height,
  });
});

canvas.setBackgroundImage(bgImg);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/upg0tyvz/1/

Comment: Oh thank you so much, have been itching my head about it for an hour. If you have the time, could you just conceptually explain what an asynchronous callback is. Or point me in the direction of some reference material?

Comment: Sure, really briefly, setting the src would require a network call, so it doesn't happen immediately (it is asynchronous). The callback allows you to run code after the image has been loaded. MDN has a more thorough explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

As `.setSrc` loads the image asynchronously, you need to wait for the image to finish loading before its dimensions are known

.setSrc has an optional call back argument that is called when the image has completed loading, so perhaps you can do

```
var bgImg = new fabric.Image();
bgImg.setSrc('http://www.aamcocolorado.com/images/Highway-Traffic.jpg', function() {
    bgImg.set({
        top: canvasHeight / 2,
        left: canvasWidth / 2,
        scaleX: canvasWidth/bgImg.width,
        scaleY: canvasHeight/bgImg.height,
    });
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(bgImg);
});
```